# Java Dynamic implementation of abstract method

Tags: java, dynamic, runtime

I'm trying to do the following in Java:

I have a collection of strings (anywhere between 1 and 10 000), each string contains a different method body (they are written in Java code) for the same abstract method of a class.
For example:

```
string1= "int a=1;" 
string2="System.out.println(\"HelloWorld\");"
...
```

each of the string could be an implementation of the following abstract method:

```
abstract class FOO{
    public abstract void doSomething();
}
```

For each string I'd like to generate an instance of FOO  to use.

I'm not quite sure what is the best way to go:
I've searched the web and came up with these suggestions:

- Use the java 6 compiler API to generate .class file and load them
- use a bytecode manipulation library like cglib, to modify the compile code

Is there any other suggestions, as these look a bit complicated (at least to myself)...

Thanks for your help

Edit:

I might be going the wrong way about my problem. Here is what I'm ultimately trying to achieve :

I have an interface representing a node in a tree

```
public  interface Node{
    public <T> void process(T input);
```

/* ... other methods not related to my problem ...*/
    }

When you provide an instance of T to the node it does something to it (some might need access to other methods of Node), and passes it on to the child nodes.

The problem is (the spec for the program) : the program reads and builds the nodes from text files, including that method body (the bodies are in java). It then builds the tree and returns it.

I'm under the impression that to do this, I must somehow generate an implementation of Node for each of the methods provided in the text file. I might be wrong though, and there might be a better way...

Comment: There are other, **even more complicated** options. Java is not an interpreted language, so this can't be done easily.

Comment: Why do you have up to 10,000 method bodies as text? Why not have them as compiled code?

Comment: This might be a legitimate question, **but**... I think the real problem occurs in the timeline somewhere before the origin of the "collection of strings" containing code.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I could think of many reasons for not having 10'000 compiled classes.

Comment: @rolve. Did you read that `10,000` compiled class? I read `10,000` method bodies. Which is viable to have.

Comment: @phineas - seconded. I'm reluctant to provide an answer to this question since the fundamental issue is elsewhere

Comment: @KleinThibaut - what are you actually trying to achieve / I think you should step back....

Comment: @rolve They are going to need to be compiled if they are to be run. At least normal Java code is relatively easy to edit and check in a project. A collection of Strings would be a maintenance nightmare. e.g. refactoring, static analysis, debugging

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? As in, what is the purpose of doing this?

Comment: I edited the post to explain what I am trying to achieve. It's basically a tree, where each node does "something". "Something" is determined at run-time and can be very different. For example the root node might take in an integer, and pass on to each of its children an array of length the integer provided. Then one children might fill the array with zeros, the other might use it to do something else...

Comment: I'm thinking of generating at run time source files for each class and calling the compiler on them, and then loading them. But this seems very messy and hard maintenance...

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps what you want is [BeanShell](http://www.beanshell.org/)

> BeanShell is a small, free, embeddable Java source interpreter with object scripting language features, written in Java. BeanShell dynamically executes standard Java syntax and extends it with common scripting conveniences such as loose types, commands, and method closures like those in Perl and JavaScript.
>
> You can use BeanShell interactively for Java experimentation and debugging as well as to extend your applications in new ways. Scripting Java lends itself to a wide variety of applications including rapid prototyping, user scripting extension, rules engines, configuration, testing, dynamic deployment, embedded systems, and even Java education.
>
> BeanShell is small and embeddable, so you can call BeanShell from your Java applications to execute Java code dynamically at run-time or to provide extensibility in your applications. Alternatively, you can use standalone BeanShell scripts to manipulate Java applications; working with Java objects and APIs dynamically. Since BeanShell is written in Java and runs in the same VM as your application, you can freely pass references to "live" objects into scripts and return them as results.
>
> In short, BeanShell is dynamically interpreted Java, plus a scripting language and flexible environment all rolled into one clean package.
>
> Summary of features
>
> - Dynamic execution of the full Java syntax, Java code fragments, as well as loosely typed Java and additional scripting conveniences.
> - Transparent access to all Java objects and APIs.
> - Runs in four modes: Command Line, Console, Applet, Remote Session Server.
> - Can work in security constrained environments without a classloader or bytecode generation for most features.
> - The interpreter is small ~150K jar file.
> - Pure Java.
> - It's Free!!

---

An alternative is to use a library I wrote which wraps the Compiler API so that it compiles in memory and loads into the current ClassLoader (by default)

http://sourceforge.net/projects/essence/files/Essence%20Java%20Config.%20Files/Essence%20JCF%201.02/

http://vanillajava.blogspot.co.uk/2010/11/more-uses-for-dynamic-code-in-java.html

```
// this writes the file to disk only when debugging is enabled.
CachedCompiler cc = CompilerUtils.DEBUGGING ?
        new CachedCompiler(new File(parent, "src/test/java"), new File(parent, "target/compiled")) :
        CompilerUtils.CACHED_COMPILER;

String text = "generated test " + new Date();
Class fooBarTeeClass = cc.loadFromJava("eg.FooBarTee", "package eg;\n" +
    '\n' +
    "import eg.components.BarImpl;\n" +
    "import eg.components.TeeImpl;\n" +
    "import eg.components.Foo;\n" +
    '\n' +
    "public class FooBarTee{\n" +
    "    public final String name;\n" +
    "    public final TeeImpl tee;\n" +
    "    public final BarImpl bar;\n" +
    "    public final BarImpl copy;\n" +
    "    public final Foo foo;\n" +
    '\n' +
    "    public FooBarTee(String name) {\n" +
    "        // when viewing this file, ensure it is synchronised with the copy on disk.\n" +
    "        System.out.println(\"" + text + "\");\n" +
    "        this.name = name;\n" +
    '\n' +
    "        tee = new TeeImpl(\"test\");\n" +
    '\n' +
    "        bar = new BarImpl(tee, 55);\n" +
    '\n' +
    "        copy = new BarImpl(tee, 555);\n" +
    '\n' +
    "        // you should see the current date here after synchronisation.\n" +
    "        foo = new Foo(bar, copy, \"" + text + "\", 5);\n" +
    "    }\n" +
    '\n' +
    "    public void start() {\n" +
    "    }\n" +
    '\n' +
    "    public void stop() {\n" +
    "    }\n" +
    '\n' +
    "    public void close() {\n" +
    "        stop();\n" +
    '\n' +
    "    }\n" +
    "}\n");

// add a debug break point here and step into this method.
FooBarTee fooBarTee = new FooBarTee("test foo bar tee");
Foo foo = fooBarTee.foo;
assertNotNull(foo);
assertEquals(text, foo.s);
```

Comment: Never heard of it. And I can't follow the link - Blocked in my office. Can you please explain exactly what is it for?

Comment: This website certainly looks outdated. And the JSR which is linked is dormant since 2005. Is this thing usable?

Comment: Its more than tens years and widely used by debuggers to evaluate expressions dynamically.

Comment: @RohitJain So free its has `!!` ;)